# She hopes that she will get a loan from her bank

Tags: present-tense, to-infinitive, future-constructions, noun-clause

1. She hopes **to get** a loan from her bank to help her out of her financial predicament.
2. She hopes **that she will get** a loan from her bank to help her out of her financial predicament.
3. She is hoping **to get** a loan from her bank to help her out of her financial predicament.
4. She is hoping **that she will get** a loan from her bank to help her out of her financial predicament.

Q1) Are they all correct/idiomatic?

Q2) Is there any difference between (1) and (2) or (3) and (4)?

Q3) In all of them, do the words "hopes" and "is hoping" refer to her hopes for the *present*?

Comment: Hi! Please make a few edits to your question. 1) Requests for proofreading are not [on-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so "are they all correct" is too broad. If you have specific grammatical concerns, talk about them directly. 2) "Is there any difference" questions are tricky; there's almost always *some* difference. Maybe you want to ask about *how much* difference (in this case, not much). and...

Comment: 3) Your question about "hopes"/"is hoping" is easier to answer. However, you might want to clarify: yes, the *verb tenses* are present, but a hope is often "for" the future. Are you asking about verb tense, or about implied meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. All of these sentences are correct and will be easily understood.

Q2. There are some subtle meaning differences between these sentences.  "She hopes" from the first two statements denotes a level of certainty about the plans she's making.  Maybe she has generally good credit and income, but her dog just got sick and she needs a loan to cover the vet visit.  She thinks that she will get approved for the loan and is making plans assuming she will get the money, but she does not currently have the loan approval.  The bank might still deny her request.

"She is hoping" suggests less certainty about the future proposed.  Maybe this time, she also just lost her job or her credit is not as good.  The bank might give her the money, but she should also look for another alternative or backup plan.  There is not enough certainty to make this her only plan and if she cannot make other plans, she may end up without any option to avoid her financial predicament.

"To get" vs "that she will get" are a lot more interchangeable.  "That she will get" is slightly more formal and stilted.  It like speaking to your boss's boss or something your awkward friend might say that, but it isn't robot awkward.  Also, the word "that" can be implied and that will help relax the sentence.  "She hopes to get a loan" or "She hopes she will get a loan" are valid and relaxed versions of the above statements.

Q3. In all sentences, she currently has hopes about her future state.  All of these are in the present tense, but the word "hope" implies something about the future being different from the present.  If she already was approved for the loan, she would not be hoping for it since she already has it.  Similarly if she was already denied her loan, she would not have any hope because there is no chance for a change to help her out.  It is only now when she might or might not get the loan that she hopes for the better option.